# How to find an error in a huge file?

Tags: pdftex

I have [this file](https://github.com/yashkes/Summaries/blob/master/QFT2_Summary.tex) which was produced by Lyx and it wouldn't compile, not in LyX nor in pdflatex. The error message is:

```
$ pdflatex QFT2_Summary.tex 
 This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./QFT2_Summary.tex
LaTeX2e <2014/05/01>
Babel <3.9k> and hyphenation patterns for 78 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/jknapltx/mathrsfs.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cancel/cancel.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/esint/esint.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/feyn/feyn.sty
Package: `feyn' 0.3.3 <2009/10/08 >
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/jknapltx/ursfs.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/esint/uesint.fd))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/braket/braket.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/doublestroke/dsfont.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/carlisle/slashed.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mh/breqn.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etex-pkg/etex.sty)
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
               \char 
l.3842 \cs_new:cpn { __int_compare_!=:NNw }
                                            #1#2#3 !=
?
```

The problem is that the file has 3842 lines and the error message points to the end. I have no idea how to even start tracing out this thing. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: well.. it's l3 code so it's breqn (I think that is the only package you have using l3) probably one of your other math packages is incompatible with breqn (most things are:-)

Comment: In general, to debug a big document where I don't have a clue to the origin of the error, I place an `\end{document}` right after the `\begin{document}` and see if it compiles.  If not, the problem is in the preamble.  If it compiles, then I start moving the `\end{document}` downward in the document, in successive fashion, making sure not to insert it in the middle of a group.  Each time, I recompile.  When it finally breaks the compilation, I know in which block of code the problem resides.

Comment: The solution was found on Freenode's #TEX: (16:30) ( YoungFrog) for some reason I had problems with the feyn package. loaded before breqn, the latter would make errors. loaded after it, I had some sort of infloop (latex would not end the 
                     compilation).
(16:30) ( YoungFrog) in this latter problem, the culprit was the '!' sign (for factorial).
(16:31) ( YoungFrog) my solution is : call the package as: \usepackage[noglobalbang]{feyn} *after* calling breqn.

Comment: @David Carlisle: I would say that Steven B. Segletes comment is a much more useful answer. -it answers the OP title question. -and it is of general interest to other future readers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In general, to debug a big document where I don't have a clue to the
>   origin of the error, I place an \end{document} right after the
>   \begin{document} and see if it compiles. If not, the problem is in the
>   preamble. If it compiles, then I start moving the \end{document}
>   downward in the document, in successive fashion, making sure not to
>   insert it in the middle of a group. Each time, I recompile. When it
>   finally breaks the compilation, I know in which block of code the
>   problem resides.

–  Steven B. Segletes